# Filter a directory to show directories larger than 1 GB

Tags: linux, size

I've used the following command to list any file/directory, sorted by size:

```
du -sh * | sort -hr
```

How can I modify this to show only files/directories larger than 1GB?

Comment: Since you have `-h` switch, directories greater will have size and then letter G. So you can add `| grep -P "\d+G"` at the end. This method is not 100% right because some directory names may match too if they have digit followed by G in their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is is bigger that 1GB, it will show the size in GB or bigger (I don't know what comes after Tera).

```
du -sh -- * | sort -hr | awk '$1 ~ /[GT]/'
```

Comment: Note that because of rounding `du -h` starts outputting `1G` for values less than 1 gibibyte.

Comment: The order may not be correct as you lose information when you use `-h`. It's better to sort on row data and convert to "human-readable" form afterwards.

Comment: When one isn't sure exactly which values to include, it can sometimes be effective to exclude the values that are known to be excluded.  Specifically, you might consider `du -sh -- * | sort -hr | awk '$1 ~ /[^KM0]$/'`.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
du -sk -- * | sort -rn | awk '$1 < 1048576 {exit}; 1'
```

Comment: Or on a GNU system `du -0 --block-size=1 -s -- * | sort -zrn | gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '$1 < 2**30 {exit}; 1' | numfmt --to=iec -z | tr '\0' '\n'` to get the human-readable output and handle newline characters in file names. See also the `--count-links` option